# Timer in waiting game like clash of clans in iOS, clock change user proof

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate, nstimer

I've read [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78629/how-to-make-a-waiting-game-like-farmville-with-sprite-kit-and-swift) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629596/local-native-ios-time-hack-proof-background-count-down-timer), but when i use `NSDate()` or `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` it is easy to trigger by the user setting the clock forward.

If i use `CACurrentMediaTime()`, the countdown seems not accurate at long time (1 hour or more).

How can I check the passed time correctly?
I must check the time in a server? How?

Thanks

Comment: The only really bulletproof way of doing this is via server. However if you can't do this - [this answer may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36204651/2976878).

Comment: @originaluser2 thanks, which server do you prefer?

Comment: Your own server would be best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free service such as http://timezonedb.com/api to get the current time. You just need to register for a free API key. No need to add all the extra time of implementing your own server for a simple task like getting the time